# MySQL Datetime & timestamp for row level and table level

Tags: mysql, database, datetime, timestamp

I need to have three columns in all my tables to reflect these as per requirements:

- Create date/time -> Date and time the
  row was created. This value should
  never change forever.
- Modified date/time -> Date and time only
  portions of the row was last modified.
  This value will always change if any
  detail in the row is changed.
- Updated date/time -> Date and time
  the entire row was last updated. This
  value will always change if all
  details in the row is changed.

In addition I need to maintain same details but at table level->
 - date/time table was created
 - date/time the last row was inserted
 - date/time last edit took place.

So two questions:

1) For the 3 row cases of date/times: Which one needs to be datetime and which one timestamp?
2) For the 3 table level date/times: Can I store this in the same table somehow or do i need a separate table to store this info, and what functions can i use for this?

End goal is to automate these date/times, because lot of data like for lookup tables will be entered/edited by end users from the front end so I need the DB to do all date/times on its own in the back without any manual insertions for these colunms.

Also, I need to perform reporting on these date/times, hence need to ensure they can be manipulated at the code level for breaking down the date/times into days, weeks, months, years, hours & minutes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm afraid, that is not possible. It is a really stupid drawback but [in the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/timestamp.html) it says:

> For one TIMESTAMP column in a table,
>   you can assign the current timestamp
>   as the default value and the
>   auto-update value. It is possible to
>   have the current timestamp be the
>   default value for initializing the
>   column, for the auto-update value, or
>   both. It is not possible to have the
>   current timestamp be the default value
>   for one column and the auto-update
>   value for another column.

Table level timestamp and reporting can by done straightforward using `MAX()` and `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Kudos to the one who proves me wrong. I hate this limitation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this entirely with SQL, rather than calculating update timestamps in your application code, you'll have to add a another table. Your main table will have only one timestamp field- the creation date, which will default to CURRENT_TIMESTAMP and never change. Your 2nd table, main_updates, will be something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE main_updates(
main_id INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL REFERENCES main(main_id),
update_type ENUM('partial','complete'),
update_time TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT TIMESTAMP)
```

Then you have a choice. If you want a record of all updates ever done, don't set a primary key and only INSERT into this table.  If you want to record only the most recent values, set the primary key to be main_id together with update_type, and set update_time to `ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Then you can write a trigger to fire whenever you update main.

But really, it's much easier just to let your application layer set the update times.

Comment: Why cant i have one timestamp for current now and two datetime with Now() - one for full row update and one for partial row update?

Comment: @Dia: Well, that would be putting the information into the query (which is sent from the application layer), not making the update time intrinsic to the table, which seemed to be what you were asking.  To rephrase my answer "But really, it's much easier just to construct the query to set the update times."